# Flashing BeagleBone Black from microSD card?

Tags: installation, debian, sd-card, beagleboneblack, flashing

I am trying to flash a BeagleBone Black from a microSD card. Here are my steps:

1. Insert 8GB microSD into reader on computer
2. `dd bs=1M if=debian-jessie-console-armhf-flasher-2015-02-25-2gb.img of=/dev/sdc1`
3. Open gparted, make sure /dev/sdc1 has boot flag
4. Remove microSD from computer, insert into BBB
5. Hold S2 button and insert miniUSB for power

However, nothing happens. The LEDs do not flash and the BBB does not even boot normally. If I remove the miniUSB and reinsert it without holding S2, it boots its old install on the eMMC. I have also tried this method with the `bone-debian-8.7-lxqt-4gb-armhf-2017-03-19-4gb.img` image, same result.

I have also tried booting the BBB normally and running `./init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh`, but it only gives this output before exiting:

```
Starting eMMC Flasher
-----------------------------
Checking for Valid BBB EEPROM header
```

At this point I am stumped because this is all the documentation I can find. This should work, and I have `dd`'d five different cards and tested on three different BBBs now with no results.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out the problem. In `dd`, you are supposed to write *directly* to the SD card device, **NOT** not to a specific partition of said device.

**DO NOT** do this:
`dd if=debian-jessie-console-armhf-flasher-2015-02-25-2gb.img of=/dev/sdc1`

Instead, **DO THIS:** `dd if=debian-jessie-console-armhf-flasher-2015-02-25-2gb.img of=/dev/sdc`

Notice that in the second example, I did not include the `1` at the end of `/dev/sdc` to specify a partition.

Comment: Note that this is not the latest image. https://beagleboard.org/latest-images  - For instructions on how to turn an image into a flasher: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Flashing_eMMC